# How to set image sizes for NextGen masonry gallery

Tags: css, wordpress, image, plugins

I have created a Masonry Gallery using the NextGen WordPress plugin and need to know how to size the portrait and landscape images and also specify the layout. How do I do so?

Answer (score 0):

you can define size in your functions.php

```
     add_image_size( 'nextgen_size', 800, 800, $crop = true);
```

Some thing like that.